# Issue with csv format when sent with mailR package

Tags: r, email, csv

I am creating a csv file from a data frame (df) and writing it using `write.csv(df,file="file.csv")`

The data frame contains column names with spaces in them (like "Start Date" for instance).
Those names are correctly parsed by `write.csv` function and the csv file contains those spaces.
However when I include the csv in a mail sent with the `sent.mail()` function (with the argument `attach.files=paste(getwd(),"file.csv",sep="")`) of the `mailR` package the spaces have disappeared and were replaced by dots (ex: Start.Date) when the e-mail is received.
Example:

```
df=data.frame(c1=c(1,1),c2=c(2,2))
names(df)<-c("c 1","c 2")
write.csv(df,file="file.csv",row.names=F)
  send.mail(from = "youremail@gmail.com",
          to = "youremail@gmail.com",
          subject = "Exemple",
          body = "I attached file.csv",
          attach.files = paste0(getwd(),"/file.csv"), 
          smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
          authenticate = FALSE,
          send = TRUE)
```

It seems this toy example works correctly so I am even more lost. Could it be possible that the cause would be because the code is ran from a server ?
What is happening here ? And can I change it ? Those are my questions.

Comment: Please edit you question and make it a full reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `read.csv` function, if you do not provide the `check.names = FALSE` argument the variable names will be stripped of spaces.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5))

df[["Start Date"]] <- rep(as.Date(Sys.time()), 5)

write.csv(df, file = "file.csv", row.names = FALSE)

read.csv("file.csv")
           a Start.Date
1 -0.3690216 2015-12-15
2 -0.4973525 2015-12-15
3  0.2314902 2015-12-15
4  0.8877708 2015-12-15
5 -0.9476200 2015-12-15

read.csv("file.csv", check.names = FALSE)
           a Start Date
1 -0.3690216 2015-12-15
2 -0.4973525 2015-12-15
3  0.2314902 2015-12-15
4  0.8877708 2015-12-15
5 -0.9476200 2015-12-15
```

Now as it turns out, if you add the `check.names = FALSE` argument into your `send.mail()` function, you will receive an attachment that has no dots in the variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer choff  !